# Book from childhood with some sort of shuttle craft crashed on a mountain

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm trying to remember the title to a book that I read some time in the 80s I think.  The only thing I have to go on is what the cover of the paperback looked like.  I'll try to describe as much detail as possible.

The main color of the book cover is blue.  There is a large gray mountain which we are zoomed up against.  Against the mountain is a small crashed space ship or some form of what I'll call a shuttlecraft (e.g. it is meant for traversing around a planet, not into space).  It looks like it could seat 1-2 people.  It has a clear sphere dome over the cockpit.

Comment: If you read that book, please give us details of the story, not of the cover of the book. Different editions might change the cover. The story/plot is something that we can recognize.

Comment: I'd imagine there might be hundreds of covers with that general description...

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remember anything about the plot.

Comment: @Mike. Perhaps it will help if you try to explain why you want to read it again. Was there something about the story that intrigued you. Something that maybe linked to another storyline or other external event that might give a clue as to the plot within the book?  As Chris notes, this is a pretty generic cover for a science fiction novel. Too, as a thought, do you remember if it was hard-cover or soft-cover?  Perhaps where you read it?  E.g. was it a juvenile fiction book you may have read in school?  Some other questions. Were people by the ship? Was the ship crashed or simply landed?

Comment: @beichst It was soft cover.  I definitely read it (not sure if I finished it) when I was either in the 8th grade (USA) or just barely in high school (9th grade, maybe 10th).

Answer (score 3):

You can probably find it looking through these site:

- http://scifibookart.com/
- http://www.penguinsciencefiction.org/
- http://www.goodshowsir.co.uk/

Could It be:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(okay this one is just actual crazy looking)

Comment: Sorry, it was none of those.  I'm still looking.  If I find it, I will post back.

Comment: Is it just me or do the spaceships on the *Beyond the Stars* cover look like they're from the original *Battlestar Galactica*?

Comment: @Alan - They're very similar indeed. My guess is that there was originally going to be a battlestar story in the book (along with the Star Wars and Doctor Who stories) which got pulled. They kept the cover.